# SQLite outer query is returning results not found in inner query

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, distinct

I just wondered if anyone has run into a case in SQLite (3.7.4) where a query would return one set of results, and when it becomes a subquery the results are completely different? I found the problem in a more complex query, but here's a simpler example that demonstrates the same behavior:

**Database setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE "test" ("letter" VARCHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY, "number" INTEGER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO "test" ("letter", "number") VALUES('b', 1);
INSERT INTO "test" ("letter", "number") VALUES('a', 2);
INSERT INTO "test" ("letter", "number") VALUES('c', 2);
```

**Initial query:**

```
SELECT "letter", "number" FROM "test" ORDER BY "letter", "number" LIMIT 1;
```

This returns `a|2`, the second row from the results as you would expect given that we're sorting on the letter then the number. However, here's what I did not expect:

**Initial query as a subquery:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT "number" FROM (SELECT "letter", "number" FROM "test" ORDER BY "letter", "number" LIMIT 1) AS "test";
```

This returns `1`, which is not at all what I expected. What I expected to see is `2`. My understanding of how a subquery works is that it should return the same results *as if* the inner query was materialized, and the outer query was applied against those results (even though I realize that databases go to extreme lengths not to materialize results until necessary).

Is my assumption incorrect? I tested the same query in PostgreSQL and MySQL and it worked as I expected (i.e. it returned `2`). What it looks like to me is that I've hit a bug in how SQLite collapses subqueries, but I'm not sure.

Just to reiterate, the above example is simplified from what I'm actually doing. I'm not just using DISTINCT on a subquery that returns a single row, but rather it returns many rows, some of which have the same value for a column hence my need for DISTINCT. The above example is the simplest way I could think of to demonstrate what's happening.

EDIT: I was able to disable the incorrect subquery folding by adding `OFFSET 0` to the inner query, e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "number" FROM (SELECT "letter", "number" FROM "test" ORDER BY "letter", "number" LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) AS "test";
```

I'll be reporting this as a bug through the SQLite mailing list, and this as a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can verify that it happens with SQLite add-on for Firefox as well.

If it is any consolation, this form works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "number" FROM (SELECT "letter", "number" FROM "test"
ORDER BY "letter", "number") AS "test" ORDER BY "letter" LIMIT 1;
```

I believe the SQLite spec ignores the LIMIT clause in inner queries and migrates it outside.  Without the limit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "number" FROM (SELECT "letter", "number" FROM "test"
ORDER BY "letter", "number") AS "test";
```

It returns

```
1
2
(2 rows)
```

Interesting to note that this also returns the correct results

```
SELECT number FROM (SELECT letter, number FROM test
ORDER BY letter, number LIMIT 1) AS test;
```

The two plans can be compared using EXPLAIN.
DESCRIBE is adding a lot of operations, in-lining and optimizing the inner query (incorrectly).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Now that I have that, I'm going to report this as a bug through the proper channels.